# Cypress - Typescript - How can i make my fixture variables global?

Tags: typescript, cypress, fixtures

Fairly new to Cypress/Typescript etc, i want to grab a value from my fixture and make it usable for the 'perform search and verify returned header is correct' test. However i cant seem to access the variable from within my test, any help appreciated:

Here's the values in my fixture:

```
{
  "manufacturer": "Dyson",
  "product": "9kJ Hand Dryer"

}
```

Here's my code that creates an alias from the fixture and attempts to access the variable, but im getting the following error: Cannot find name 'manuTerm'

```
describe('scenario-one', () => {
beforeEach(() => {// I need these variables availabe to multiple tests
cy.fixture('manufacturer').as('manuTerm');
});

it ('perform search and verify returned header is correct', () => {
    const lp = new sourceElements();
    lp.enterSearchTerm(manuTerm.manufacturer);
    lp.verifySearchResult(manuTerm.manufacturer);
});
});
```

[Current errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNQCj.jpg)

[manuTerm: any](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOECZ.png)

Comment: Is your JSON file at the root level inside the fixtures folder or there are some sub folders inside the fixtures folder?

Comment: Its at the root level, no sub folders. As im using an Alias ive seen people use this syntax: lp.enterSearchTerm(this.manuTerm.manufacturer);      ie putting a 'this' in front of the fixture call, that didnt work either

Comment: Are you using `this.manuTerm.manufacturer` or `manuTerm.manufacturer`, as the code snippet mentioned in the post doesn't have `this`?

Answer (score 1):

`this` working for me. But have you try create a high var?

```js
describe('scenario-one', () => {
  let manu: any;
  before(() => {
    cy.fixture('manufacturer').then((val: any) => {
      manu = val;
    });
  });

  it('perform search and verify returned header is correct', () => {
    const lp = new sourceElements();
    lp.enterSearchTerm(manu.manufacturer);
    lp.verifySearchResult(manu.manufacturer);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
describe('scenario-one', function() {
      beforeEach(() => { // I need these variables availabe to multiple tests
        cy.fixture('manufacturer').then(function(manuTerm:any) {
          this.manuTerm = manuTerm
          })
        })

        it('perform search and verify returned header is correct', () => {
          const lp = new sourceElements();
          lp.enterSearchTerm(this.manuTerm.manufacturer);
          lp.verifySearchResult(this.manuTerm.manufacturer);
        })
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately your suggested code didnt work. I had previously tried using the 'this.manuTerm.manufacturer' sytax but with no success. I now have 2 errors but i dont really understand them:

'The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.'
'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.'

Comment: @Sam2142 Can you post a screenshot of your error here. Also I removed the arrow from `beforeEach ` and `describe `and instead I am using the keyword **function**. Can you try with this once.

Comment: Ive added a link to a screenshot showing my code (current errors) and the 2 errors i'm getting. The highlighted code is having the issue. If i add your 'function' instead of the => to the ''perform search and verify returned header is correct' test, i get another typescript error saying something like - use of this function is forbidden

Comment: @Sam2142 I have updated my answer, mind giving it a try now. I have added `manuTerm:any` in `beforeEach()`

Comment: Ive added that syntax but the its like the fixture data just isnt available inside my test. Ive added another screenshot showing the issues. Note: I could access the fixture data if i included the fixture call within the test itself, but obviously this isnt the best solution as i only want to do this once, not within each test...hope that made sense

Comment: Hi, its working now, thanks for your help, i added the function() bit to my test and although typescript is complaining about the following, i disabled the warnings and it works:
only-arrow-functions
ter-prefer-arrow-callback

So i think the issue was with TypeScript, in that it didnt like the use of function(), it prefers the => syntax

TSLint extention has highlighted all of my code, i assumed it was broken but it was only showing me a warning...at least its working now, thanks for the help again