# Cypress Global variable can not be refereed

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

My code is like below...

```
describe('The Home Page',() =>{

before(()=>{
    cy.fixture('WorkHours').then(function(data){
        this.xxx = data
        cy.log(this.xxx.weekDate+'..One')
    })
})

it( 'checkNavis',() =>{
    cy.log(this.xxx.weekDate+'..two')
    cy.visit('/')
```

Gets an error ....[[Cypress Log]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLIUt.png)
[image]

why dose it not referring to global variable?

1. could not be synchronization problem since waiting for promises??
2. since xxx is a declared global, shouldn't be scope??

this is related but doesn't give me a clue to identify problem...
[Cypress - Typescript - How can i make my fixture variables global?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301256/cypress-typescript-how-can-i-make-my-fixture-variables-global)

Comment: Not sure, but try this `it( 'checkNavis', function() {`. [Sharing context](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Sharing-Context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tests or hooks you cannot access aliases using `this.*` using arrow functions.

This is most likely because when `this` is used in an arrow functions it will have the same value as the context in which the arrow function was created (ie. undefined). The classic function () has its own `this` which is has global access.

Another example of this behaviour is in `mocha`. It has a [restriction on the use of arrow](https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions) functions.

Instead try:

```
describe('The Home Page',() =>{
    before(function() {
        cy.fixture('WorkHours').then(function(data){
            this.xxx = data
            cy.log(this.xxx.weekDate+'..One')
        })
    })

    it('checkNavis', function() {
        cy.log(this.xxx.weekDate + '..two')
        cy.visit('/')
```